# GCP Compute Engine instance all port connections refused besides 22 (SSH)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, port, google-compute-engine

I have a GCP compute engine instance where I've been trying to open several external ports. I am unable to connect to my static external IP and also unable to connect within the cloud shell using curl localhost:80 or localhost:443.

I have added multiple firewall rules which should allow access.
Output of firewall rules list and nmap here https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR0sV.jpg

I would expect to be able to make connections with all of these.

Edit: image with *targets* https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agiq3.jpg

Comment: Show how you are assigning a firewall rule to an instance (hint: network tags).

Comment: Edited with info.

Comment: 1) I do not see a rule allowing port 443. 2) I do not see any services listening on either port 80 or 443.

Comment: Note: Do not include links to screenshots in your question. All details must be in your question without clicking links to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous comments by `john-hanley@`, default HTTP and HTTPS firewall rules are applied to GCE instances using the [network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#externalhttpconnection), you will need to check the `Allow HTTP traffic` and `Allow HTTPS traffic` while creating the GCE instance or by editing the existing VM instance. Also as mentioned it seems there is nothing listening on the mentioned ports as seen in the screenshot for nmap scan. port 80 http is closed.